# Multiprocessing hanging in Spyder

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder, pool

I have been trying the `pool.map()` multiprocessing with python3 and not matter how I simplify my function it hangs and shows that the code is still running and gives no results.
I am using Windows.Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp    

def f(x):
    return x + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))
```

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?
Thanks!